# How can I get FileZilla to ignore folder that have more than 1000 files?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I want to backup my website to my computer, but there are cache folders which I don't want to backup it, and it is take very long time.

How to ignore folders have **more than 1000 files** from transfer in FilaZilla?

Comment: Or, purge the caches.

Comment: @K7AAY I can't delete it. Every moment there are new cached files.

Comment: Aha. See Martin's answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *View > Directory Listing Filters*.

There you can exclude the folder and files you do not want to download.

Comment: Thank you but I want better than this solution, why? Becuase there are a lot of new cache folders every time

Comment: As I asked. Auto ignore folders that have more than 1000 files.

Comment: FileZilla does not have such option. And I doubt any other FTP client have. Did you consider using a script for that? After all, it's for backup purposes. You may want to run the backup automatically/on schedule, not manually from FileZilla.

Comment: Thank you for your help Martin.